# Understanding the indices in a Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, summation, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

Sometimes the truncated Fourier series of a function with Fourier coefficients $\hat{u}_k$ is written

$$\sum_{k=-N}^N\hat{u}_ke^{ikx}$$

which is a linear combination of $\cos(nx) +i\sin(nx)$ for integers $|n|\le N$.  Sometimes, however, the truncated Fourier series is written

$$\sum_{k=-N/2}^{N/2-1}\hat{u}_ke^{ikx}$$

which is a linear combination of $\cos(nx/2) +i\sin(nx/2)$ for integers $-N\le n\le N-2$.

What motivates using the latter less-intuitive indices?  Are both series given above the same?  Functions such as $\cos(nx/2)$ for odd $n$ are not even periodic on $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Something that looks odd and unmotivated without context can make perfect sense within the context. In what context have you encountered the latter notation?